# I want to know how can i add text on particular image in a slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, slider

I made a slider with the help of HTML,CSS and Jquery but i want to write a text on a particular image of the slider. I tried very much to add the text but the text began to come in all the images.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WQY3e/)

**Here is my Jquery:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {

   var imgFirst = $('#img-grp-wrap .img-wrap img');
$('#img-grp-wrap .img-wrap img:gt(0)').hide();

var rotate = setInterval(function() {
    slideShow();
}, 4000);

$('#img-grp-wrap .prev, #img-grp-wrap .next').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(rotate);
}, function() {
    rotate = setInterval(function() {
        slideShow();
    }, 4000);
});

$('#img-grp-wrap .next').click(function() {
    imgFirst.filter(":first-child") 
    .stop().fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
});

$('#img-grp-wrap .prev').click(function() {
    imgFirst.filter(":first-child").stop().fadeOut();
    $('#img-grp-wrap .img-wrap img:last-child').prependTo('.img-wrap').fadeOut();
    imgFirst.filter(":first-child").fadeIn();
});

function slideShow() {
    imgFirst.filter(":first-child").fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
}

});
</script>
```

**Here is my CSS**

```
 <style>#img-grp-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 610px;
}

.img-wrap img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
}

.next, .prev {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 300px;
}

.next {
    right: 0px;
}

.prev {
    left: 20px;
}
.resize {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 600;
}

.resize {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 600;
}</style>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="img-wrap">

    <img class="resize" src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/home.jpg" />

    <img class="resize" src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/previews/home/content-slider.jpg" />
    <img class="resize" src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/previews/home/video-gallery.jpg" />
    
</div>   


<img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowright.jpg" class="next" alt="Next"/> 
<img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowleft.jpg" class="prev" alt="Previous"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your `html` markup any text will be available for all the images. so instead you have to wrap it up with some other html tag.

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <div class='img'>
       <img class="resize" src="...royal-slider/img/home.jpg" />
       <h3>First image text.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='img'>
       <img class="resize" src="...royal-slider/.../content-slider.jpg" />
       <h3>Second image text.</h3>
    </div>
    ....and so on....
</div>
```

so in your css you have to set `h3's` `z-index` property to higher with absolutely positioned element.

---

#### note:

Although there are several other ways too, but you have to make sure that your demo fiddle works.

Comment: Hey please explain much more about it

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the Fiddle with the markup you would require for HTML and CSS. Change the JS accordingly. Shouldn't need much time figure out what is required.

```
<div class="img-wrap">
  <ul>
   <li class="slider-content first">
       <img class="resize" src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/home.jpg" />
       <h2> This is the first picture</h2>
   </li>

    <li class="slider-content">
        <img class="resize" src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/previews/home/content-slider.jpg" />
    </li>

    <li class="slider-content">
        <img class="resize" src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/previews/home/video-gallery.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-wrap .slider-content.first h2{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1;
    color:white;
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE WITH MARKUP**](http://jsfiddle.net/WQY3e/7/)

Comment: Hey i wanted a text on a particular image not on all the images